# scp files from raspberry pi to mac using bash script

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi

I am trying to copy files from my raspberry pi to mac using a bash script. I was able to find the relevant files and I checked to ensure my directories were correct. Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(ssh pi@192.168.0.101 ls -1 FlightLog* | sort -t_ -k2 -nr | head -1)
scp pi@192.168.0.101:home/pi/"$var" ykathur2@wirelessprv-10-192-192- 
127.near.illinois.edu/Users/ykathur2/bin
```

And here is the error I got:

```
Shared connection to 192.168.0.101 closed.
scp: home/pi/FlightLog_89.dat: No such file or directory
```

I have also tried using `sftp` command and I got other bugs. Does anybody know what is going on? And what is the best way of copying files using a bash script?

EDIT: Found out why it was not working. The correct `scp` format is:

```
scp pi@192.168.0.101:/home/pi/"$var" /Users/ykathur2/bin
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `scp pi@192.168.0.101:/home/pi/"$var" ykathur2@wirelessprv-10-192-192- 
127.near.illinois.edu:/Users/ykathur2/bin` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use rsync for better throughput; something like

```
rsync -mauvPAX pi@192.168.0.101:'~/FlightLog*' ykathur2@wirelessprv-10-192-192-127.near.illinois.edu:/Users/ykathur2/log/
```

Comment: So I tried using this format to search a directory and get the file stored inside that directory. My command went:`rsync -mauvPAX pi@192.168.0.101:'~/sess*/log001.ulg' ykathur2@wirelessprv-10-192-19-127.near.illinois.edu:/Users/ykathur2/log/`
And I got the following error: `rsync: -mauvPAX: unknown option rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync- 52/rsync/main.c(1337) [client=2.6.9]`

Comment: looks like your version of rsync doesn't support all of the flags. Try `rsync -av` and keep adding the flags that you need until it errors.